# Unable to insert foreign keys with doctrine 2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

here is my code for insertion

```
$checklist = new Report();
$project = $entityManager
            ->find('Application\Entity\Projects',$projectId);
$level = $entityManager
            ->find('Application\Entity\LdDynamicLevels',$postArray['level']);
$building = $entityManager
            ->find('Application\Entity\LdDynamicBuildings',$postArray['building']);
$checklist->setLdDynamicBuilding($building);
$checklist->setLdDynamicLevel($level);
$checklist->setProject($project);
$entityManager->merge($checklist);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Now the thing is when i run the code its say, the building value is null, although when is dump the building record it has the required value
this code for **$building:**

```
$buildingId = Building->getBuildingId();
echo $buildingId;
```

is printing the value, so that means the building is not empty
please help

Comment: Can you please provide your `Report` class? Also I believe it would be better to call persist instead of merge.

Comment: well, i am updating the record as well, so in that case i need to use merge.
and the insertion is working fine for some values,or if i manually insert values

Comment: $building = $entityManager
      ->find('Application\Entity\LdDynamicBuildings',$postArray['building']);
is not working while
$building = $entityManager
     ->find('Application\Entity\LdDynamicBuildings',8);
is working

Comment: ok, then how does $postArray['building'] look?

Comment: it has the value but there is something wrong with the value, for example 7 and 8 are both values in the building entity 7 is inserting but not 8